# I made some voting buttons (think reddit/digg/etc) however they don't work below IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml, html

http://www.projectfitfamilies.org/recipes.php?page=treats

It only works in IE8 quirks mode, standards mode doesn't do anything.  I don't have IE6 or 7 to test it out on directly, but I imagine if IE8 quirks fails, then so will IE6 and 7.

Thanks!

Per request, my content header:

header("content-type:application/xml;charset=utf-8");

Comment: If that's jQuery, adding a jQuery tag to your question would probably be a good idea.

Comment: Could you post you php header content statement.

Comment: Why are you even trying to support IE6 and IE7?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. To check out how your site works in IE7 standards mode, you can use the (F12) developer tools to change the browser mode. For IE6, I would recommend using [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage)

Comment: I had no idea about the f12 dev tools for IE.  Thanks for the protip!

Answer (score 1):

Your reciepies.php header looks something like this:

```
header("content-type:application/xml-xhtml;charset=utf-8");
```

You need to replace it with something this:

```
header("content-type:application/xml;charset=utf-8");
```

IE does not function with the xhtml.

Hope this helps, Julian

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately no cigar.  I'll keep playing with the content type though, see if I can figure it out.  I think you might be on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional comments to strip out this function. IE6/7 are very old browsers, better to write clean code than to put some hacks so site can work 100% fine (if it's not commercial project).

For my personal experience, i put links to every browser download site (beside IE) when i detect IE6/7 on personal sites. Because nice HTML4 code with modern CSS works really bad in 6/7.

Answer (score 1):

Add `#numberwrapper12 { margin-left:33px; }` to make it work in IE8 standards mode.

Seems to work fine in IE7. IE6 has some issues. Most noticeably, your sprite arrows don't display properly and you should add `.arrowwrapper a { overflow-y:hidden; } to fix that. Also the '# of votes' doesn't stay on one line. Widening the votebox by a single pixel fixes that.